# Implement efficient JQuery Image Swap

Tags: jquery, image, performance

I have around 10 links in my navigation. All of which have 2 images for example, **main_image.png** the picture that loads first, and the other that is not displayed called **main_image_up.png** This image is what I want to replace the first image with when I hover over it.

What would be the best method be/ technique to use, to incorporate all this large into a efficient function?

Here is my current code, simple structure, please note, all images will be different:

```
    <div>
<img src="http://cdn4.blogs.babble.com/strollerderby/files/2011/06/test-100x100.jpg"/>
    <p>Directory</p>
    </div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnFRa/)

Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: Did you consider using CSS Sprites instead?

Comment: No I haven't looking into it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would sprite your images and use CSS.

Take [Newgrounds.com](https://www.newgrounds.com/) for example. Have a look at their navigation bar. When you hover over it / click it, the colours change.

Now look at [the actual navigation bar image](https://www.newgrounds.com/img/bg-header/navbar.jpg).

All 3 states are one image. All they do is shift the background position of the image depending on the state of the element.

I would prefer doing this because instead of loading 20 images (10 links / 2 images each), you only load one. That saves your browser from making 19 extra calls to the server, thus saving time and speeding things up!

Have a look on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for a nice article explaining what they are, how to use them, etc.